# "Reverse universe" looking like photo-negative

Tags: story-identification

Asking this for someone who to my knowledge doesn't use StackExchange... ~20 years ago (so this must be older than that), he mentioned having seen some SF TV show or movie with a "reverse universe" with black stars on white. I recall that back then, he thought it was from somewhere in Star Trek, but I've seen most Star Trek material made up to that time and read the Star Trek Encyclopedia, and I'm pretty confident that's not it.

Comment: There is a 'reverse' effect used in Star Trek TOS Season 1 The Alternative Factor - http://www.nexusroute.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/trek-alternative4.jpg

Comment: That's why this question has been puzzling me. When this was first mentioned to me, I'd never seen Star Trek. As soon as I saw The Alternative Factor, I thought of that, but it didn't really meet the description.

Comment: Is is the black and white part of the description messing things up for you? Because, honestly, there were still tons of black and white televisions when TOS was originally on the air. It is possible the person saw the episode on a black and white tv. Heck, I was born in the 80's and remember watching black and white tvs

Comment: @NKCampbell you said that and Twilight Zone came to mind were there was a brief memory of that special effect there but I would not think this is it either. There are a lot of images of reversed shots of our galaxy.  Might be ... some combination of memories going on.

Comment: That Star Trek episode definitely had the photo-negative imaging.  Not sure why you think it doesn't fit. Do you have more details about why?

Comment: Isn't there such an effect in Clarke's *Space Odyssey* too?

Comment: Belated response to PoloHoleSet: 1, because while I don't remember the words they used originally, I know the image they conveyed was of a ship in space rather than people grappling. 2, because they watched reruns of TOS at the same time I did (1999-2000) and gave no indication they'd relocated that scene.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd like to offer an alternative: The Star Trek Animated show titled 'The Counter-Clock Incident'.  To my recollection, when the Enterprise goes through a 'warp' to a universe where time flows in reverse, space is portrayed as white, with all the stars as points of black.

Comment: That's a great addition! Can you provide some screenshots? That would be helpful for identification.

Comment: http://www.startrek.com/database_article/counter-clock-incident-the  When I said I'd seen most of (pre-1997) Star Trek, I forgot about the animated series. This does look like how I imagined the original asker's description.

Comment: I showed that page, and they said it looked familiar, so I think that's the closest I'll get to a confirmed answer.

Answer (score 7):

My guess is you're looking for the *Star Trek* episode ["The Alternative Factor"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Alternative_Factor), from series 1, episode #27.

> Anti-Lazarus calmly admits to stealing the Enterprise's dilithium. He
>   informs Kirk that his people thought that two universes exist in which
>   attempts to prove it, caused their destruction. Anti-Lazarus tells
>   Kirk that only one Lazarus can exist in one universe simultaneously.
>   Lazarus's time traveling ship is the "dimensional door," and connects
>   both Anti-Lazarus and Lazarus; only by destroying the ship with the
>   two Lazarus inside "dimensional corridor" which links the universes
>   can both universes be saved.
>
> Kirk confronts Lazarus, and pushes him into the "dimensional door."
>   Kirk heads back to the Enterprise, ordering the ship's phasers to
>   target the dimension ship. The two Lazaruses meet once more and fight
>   as phaser beams vaporize the ship, sealing the two for all of
>   eternity, caught together between universes.

It is in the "dimensional corridor" that the reverse imaging occurs.

I see that @NKCampbell has found the same episode ... so 2 people at the same time :)

Answer (score 0):

I support "The Counter-Clock Incident".

Another possibility is the first episode of The Outer Limits, in which a being transported from the Andromeda Galaxy was depicted by using negative film of his scenes.

I believe some Cthulhu Mythos stories mentioning a world in outer space with black stars in a white sky - easier written than scientifically justified.  But I doubt there have been any films showing that.